# yii reduce php memory usage on action

Tags: php, yii, memory-leaks

I am trying to pinpoint why apache some of my apache processes are using up nearly 250mb of memory. i have 4gb allocated to server and 4gb swap. halfway through the day it uses up swap space. i believe it is the php using up the memory. the following action i have found produces 96.5mb

```
public function actionView($id)
    {
        $model = $this->loadModel($id);
        $client=null;
        $obj =new GlobalController(); // preparing object

        if(strlen($model->cache(CACHE_TIMEOUT)->oRDERNO->CONTACTID) < 6){
            $client = Contacts::model()->cache(CACHE_TIMEOUT)->findByPk($model->cache(CACHE_TIMEOUT)->oRDERNO->CONTACTID);;
        }else{
            $dependency = new CDbCacheDependency('SELECT count(*) FROM sugarcrm6.contacts');
            $client = SugarContacts::model()->cache(CACHE_TIMEOUT,$dependency)->findByPk($model->cache(CACHE_TIMEOUT)->oRDERNO->CONTACTID);
        }

        // addressestransmittals
        $addressestransmittals = Addressestransmittals::model()->cache(CACHE_TIMEOUT)->findByPk($model->ORDERNO);
        //addressesconsultants
        $addressesconsultants = Addressesconsultants::model()->cache(CACHE_TIMEOUT)->findAll(array("condition"=>"ORDERNO = {$model->ORDERNO}"));

        $contactList = $obj->getContactList(array("condition"=>"(first_name is not null || (first_name is not null && last_name is not null) ) && deleted = 0", "order"=>"first_name"));
        Yii::log((memory_get_peak_usage(true))/1024/1024 . "MB",CLogger::LEVEL_INFO, __METHOD__);

        $this->render('view',array(
                'model'=>$model,
                'client'=>$client,
                'addressestransmittals'=>$addressestransmittals,
                'addressesconsultants'=>$addressesconsultants,
                'contactList'=>$contactList
        ));
    }
```

What is the best way to reduce memory usage?

I place the following just before the `render` to log the memory

```
Yii::log((memory_get_peak_usage(true))/1024/1024 . "MB",CLogger::LEVEL_INFO, __METHOD__);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the culprit it was the following line

$contactList = $obj->getContactList(array("condition"=>"(first_name is not null || (first_name is not null && last_name is not null) ) && deleted = 0", "order"=>"first_name"));

it was querying for all records in `sugarcrm` database, seems like [sugarcrm](http://www.sugarcrm.com/community) is not properly indexed, used up 70MB